Fetching data from supabase and mapping through an array of objects but unable to display the images, everything else is displayed fine / Nextjs 14
Issue displaying images
I believe this is not a Nextjs issue, since am using Nextjs Image just fine and it works with dummy data 
I've optimised for the images using Next Image so the configuration is working just fine on that aspect 
I believe the issue has to do with the image source, something about the path is an issue when I map through it 
When I fetch the data from Supabase though <br />
**Everything is displayed fine, except the images** <br />

There's an issue with the URL path, I've tried all sorts of things but failed to debug the issue <br />
Would really appreciate the help <br />

**Here's the array of objects am fetching** <br />

    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Tech Conference 2024",
            date: "May 15, 2024",
            location: "San Francisco, CA",
            description:
                "Join us for the latest in tech innovation and networking opportunities.",
            image:
                "https://utfs.io/f/4e3364dc-ea77-45e5-af07-d76af49b296c-gktlmq.jpg",
           
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Design Workshop",
            date: "June 10, 2024",
            location: "New York, NY",
            description:
                "Learn the fundamentals of design principles and tools from industry experts.",
            image:
                "https://utfs.io/f/6657b786-7f47-4563-af8d-a919d554cf2a-gktlnl.png",
        },
    
    ]

***And here's the loop am running...***

    {
        events.map((event) => (
            <section
                key={event.id}
                className="group rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-sm"
            >
                <Link href={`/events/${event.id}`}>
                    <div className="relative h-60 w-full object-cover">
                        <Image
                            className="group-hover:grayscale transition ease-in delay-150"
                            fill
                            style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
                            src={event.image}
                            alt="Event Image"
                        />
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="p-4">
                        <div className="flex items-center mb-4">
                            <div className="relative h-8 w-8 mr-2">
                                <Image
                                    fill
                                    style={{
                                        objectFit: "cover",
                                        borderRadius: "24px",
                                    }}
                                    src={event.image}
                                    alt="Organizer"
                                />
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                    {event.name}
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div className="leading-tight text-muted-foreground">
                            
                                <p className="text-sm">{event.date}</p>
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 my-2">
                                
                                <p className="text-sm">{event.location}</p>
                            </div>
    
                            <div className="text-sm">
                                {event.description}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`enter code here`
                </Link>
            </section>
        ));
    }


What is the error you get?
